# Android - resized editText with text not centered?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have problem with resized editText (I made him smaller, actually), he has 40dip height, and according to some rule, I have made text 3 times smaller, to text has 13dip (or sp). Never mind the size of the text, text inside editText is not in the middle speakoing of vercital middle. I looks weird and unprofessionaly, but I haven't found any settings how to correct that. I cannot enlarge it on it's standard size because of screen resolution... any ideas?

[image: as you see, "admin" is not in the middle, but little higher then it shlould be]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to set gravity for the text field. I'm not sure if it would help though.

Comment: so gravity for the text field don't improve anything :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside ur layout xml file, for the EditText u give,

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: I know, but it is still the same as it was before.